# My quiz() method won't update its score, how can i fix this?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm relatively inept at coding in python and as a way of practicing i tried writing a basic program to quiz people. I wrote it originally as a fully expanded program, which worked fine, so i tried to write it as a function to greatly reduce the amount of code i need. This also works  well except the score value doesn't increase for each use. The code and result is shown below:

```
def quiz(question,answer, score):
    import time
    a = raw_input(question)
    if a.lower() == answer.lower():
        score = score + 1
        if score == 1:
            print("correct! So far your score is an awesome " + str(score) + "     point")
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            print("correct! So far your score is an awesome " + str(score) + " points")
            time.sleep(0.5)
        return score
    else:
        print("wrong, dumbass! The correct answer was " + answer + "! So far your score is an abysmal " + str(score) + " points")
        time.sleep(0.5)
    actual_score = 0
    quiz("what is my favourite colour? ", "green", actual_score)
    quiz("What is my favourite game? ", "cards against humanity",    actual_score)
    quiz("Who's better: Gandalf or Dumbledore? ", "Gandalf", actual_score)
```

This returns the following:

> what is my favourite colour? green 
>   correct! So far your score is an awesome 1 point 
>   What is my favourite game? cards against humanity 
>   correct! So far your score is an awesome 1 point 
>   Who's better: Gandalf or Dumbledore? gandalf 
>   correct! So far your score is an awesome 1 point

I'm really not sure of what to do to fix this so I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two main problems:

1. You should be resetting the `score` outside the scope of your `quiz()` function
2. You should be returning the `score` var from the `quiz()` function even if the answer was wrong

Try this!

```
def quiz(question,answer, score):
    import time
    a = raw_input(question)
    if a.lower() == answer.lower():
        score = score + 1
        if score == 1:
            print("correct! So far your score is an awesome " + str(score) + "     point")
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            print("correct! So far your score is an awesome " + str(score) + " points")
            time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        print("wrong, dumbass! The correct answer was " + answer + "! So far your score is an abysmal " + str(score) + " points")
        time.sleep(0.5)

    return score    


actual_score = 0
new_score = quiz("what is my favourite colour? ", "green", actual_score)
new_score = quiz("What is my favourite game? ", "cards against humanity", new_score)
new_score = quiz("Who's better: Gandalf or Dumbledore? ", "Gandalf", new_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

You fail to save the returned score after each question.  You send the original 0 back into **quiz** each time.  Try calling it like this:

```
actual_score = 0
actual_score = quiz("what is my favourite colour? ", "green", actual_score)
actual_score = quiz("What is my favourite game? ", "cards against humanity",    actual_score)
actual_score = quiz("Who's better: Gandalf or Dumbledore? ", "Gandalf", actual_score)
```

The coding is still not up to professional standards, but that's where you're *headed*, not where you need to be now.  Keep up the good effort!

Answer (score 0):

This would be an alternative to what "tknickman" said, although still not the best approach. I would use classes, and singletons.

```
def quiz(question,answer, score):
    import time
    a = raw_input(question)
    if a.lower() == answer.lower():
        score = score + 1
        if score == 1:
            print("correct! So far your score is an awesome " + str(score) + "     point")
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            print("correct! So far your score is an awesome " + str(score) + " points")
            time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        print("wrong, dumbass! The correct answer was " + answer + "! So far your score is an abysmal " + str(score) + " points")
        time.sleep(0.5)

    return score

question_answer = list()
question_answer.append(["what is my favourite colour? ", "green"])
question_answer.append(["What is my favourite game? ", "cards against humanity"])
question_answer.append(["Who's better: Gandalf or Dumbledore? ", "Gandalf"])

actual_score = 0 

for item in question_answer:
    actual_score = quiz(*[value for value in item], actual_score)
```